# Escape character for labels in Bolt CMS

Tags: yaml, escaping, bolt-cms

When I create a field with a label in the YAML, the label is not valid when I try to add an `%` for example. The following code is my current try.

```
content_image:
    fields:
        image:
            type: image
            label: "Afbeelding 100%"
```

As a guess I tried to do use `\%` as an escape character, but that does not solve it. Reading the documentation I cannot seem to find this information, and it keeps wondering if it is possible at all.

So my question: Is there an escape character in Bolt CMS to add to labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this use case I fixed it by doing:

```
label: "Afbeelding 100% "
```

As you can see, I added a space (or any other character) after the `%` because otherwise the system would not allow it. A label can't end with a `%` for some reason, and when you place a space after a `%` there is no need for an escape character.